# Do Art and Art come back after dying in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

***Possible Spoilers***

So I went to one of my settlements and found both Arts shooting at each other. From what I've seen, the real Art died, and the synth Art lived. I killed who I think is the synth Art and got a Synth Component.

Now that they're both dead, will they ever respawn?

Comment: I don't think any special characters respawn.

Comment: @TimmyJim I don't think Art & Art are classified as special characters. They're listed under "random encounters," which, as the name suggests, happens randomly. Apparently, they can happen an unlimited amount of times, as well.

Comment: TBH, I've never even seen these characters even after 8+ days of playing the game.

Comment: @TimmyJim I've seen them a few times. I think over all my saves, I've amassed around 3-4 weeks of playtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [synth-Art's wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Art_(synth)):

> Art and "Art" will be a common recurring random encounter, ***even if both died***.

So, **yes**, this event can happen even if one or both Arts died, and can keep happening an unlimited number of times.

Comment: This is the most annoying reoccurring event in the game.  I have killed both these idiots a dozen times and they keep coming back, distracting me with their gunfire.

Comment: They both scale directly to my level too, so they have an insane amount of HP (level 98)...